# C - Comparação de strings com strcmp não funciona

Tags: c, string, malloc

Galera, estou tentando fazer uma comparação de uma string inserida pelo usuário em uma matriz dinâmica de strings com uma string pré definida. No laço DO-WHILE a repetição deveria terminar quanto a string que o usuário inserir for FIM, mas isso não acontece. O que poderia ser?

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>  


int main () {

    //declaracao de variaveis
    int linhas = 100, colunas = 500, controlador = 0;
    char limite[ ] = "FIM";
    char **frases = (char **) malloc (linhas * sizeof(char *));

        for (int i = 0 ; i < linhas ; i++)
            frases[i] = (char *) malloc (colunas * sizeof(char));

    //ler frases
    printf("\n");

    do {
        fgets(frases[controlador], colunas, stdin);
        controlador++;

    } while (strcmp(frases[controlador - 1], limite) != 0); 

    //liberar ponteiro
    for (int i = 0 ; i < linhas ; i++)
        free(frases[i]);

    free(frases);

    return 0;  //finalizar o programa

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string digitada, recebida pelo fgets(), contém o caractere de fim de linha (\n, \r ou \r\n, dependendo do sistema operacional). A sua string de comparação teria de incluir esse caractere, ou então você faz o teste de forma um pouco diferente.

No Linux, fazer a string de comparação igual a "FIM\n" resolveu o problema.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso! Usei a função strcspn pra achar a posição do \n nas strings inseridas, gravei numa variável e usei ela pra atribuir o valor nulo no lugar do \n e agora está 100% funcional e pronto. Valeuu demais!!!